# Scroll 80px above id position instead of on id position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have this snippet which on load scrolls to the `#id` on the page. The problem is our sticky navigation is `80px` tall so it covers the part I would like visible when it scrolls to that specific `#id`.

This code works great. But how do i make it scroll 80px above the id instead of exactly at the `#id`. (its a wordpress site)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   if ( $(window).width() < 768){ 
    if( $('body.woocommerce-page').length || $('body.single-product').length ){
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#scrollto1").offset().top}, 1250); 
    }
   }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subtract 80 from the `.offset().top`. See below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   if ( $(window).width() < 768){ 
    if( $('body.woocommerce-page').length || $('body.single-product').length ){
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#scrollto1").offset().top - 80}, 1250); 
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. Says i have to wait more time before awarding answer.

Comment: @PortalP np :) Happy to help.